# Can't import a ViewPort3D from external XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, import, 3d

I can't import a XAML with a Viewport3d inside. 
This is my code:

```
OpenFileDialog Fd = new OpenFileDialog();
Fd.ShowDialog();
string LoadedFileName = Fd.FileName;

//Load the file
FileStream Fs = new FileStream(@LoadedFileName, FileMode.Open);
Grid grdToLoad = new Grid();
grdToLoad.Height = 210;
grdToLoad.Width = 400;

grdToLoad = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(Fs) as Grid;

grdLoadXAML.Children.Add(grdToLoad);

Fs.Close();
```

And this is the [XAML](http://tny.cz/1d7f7247) (had to upload on another site 'cause it was far too long)

This code doesn't show anything. I don't know what to do and I really need to import a 3d Model, converted in XAML.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this tutorial how to save 3d object from Blender to Expression Blend **http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xg0p-5TJ46k**